# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen »froh« und »fröhlich«?

Tags: adjective, meaning-in-context, synonym

In der Vorweihnachtszeit sind [»froh«](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/froh) und [»fröhlich«](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/fr%C3%B6hlich) häufig gesehene Adjektive, die anscheinend austauschbar sind:

> Frohe Weihnachten - Fröhliche Weihnacht

Tatsächlich führen die gängigen Wörterbücher beide Varianten als Synonyme auf und geben in den Bedeutungserklärungen das jeweils andere Wort an.

Dennoch scheint es Unterschiede zu geben, wenn man folgende Beispiele betrachtet, in denen *»froh«* und *»fröhlich«* nicht austauschbar sind:

> - Ich bin **froh**, dass ich meine Arbeit noch vor den Ferien erledigen konnte.
> - Jessica ist ein **fröhliches** Kind.
> - Zu meiner Geburtstagsparty hatten wir eine **fröhliche** Gesellschaft beisammen.
> - Das ist aber eine **frohe** Botschaft, dass Du Dein Examen bestanden hast!

Ist diese verschiedene Verwendung von *»froh«* und *»fröhlich«* nur Folge fester Wendungen, oder gibt es tatsächlich feine Bedutungsunterschiede?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Froh kann ein stiller, tiefer Zustand sein, welcher einem unter Umständen nicht anzumerken ist.
 Dem gegenüber ist Fröhlichkeit von außen erkennbar und muß kein tiefes Empfinden beinhalten.

> der fröhliche ist gleichsam halbfroh, beginnt sich zu freuen, frohe empfindung, froher mut gehen tiefer als eine blosz fröhliche, als ein fröhlicher. doch werden beide wörter fast ganz gleich genommen und angewendet <sup>[Grimm Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF09566)</sup>

Siehe auch:

- [Johann August Eberhards - Synonymisches Handwörterbuch](http://www.textlog.de/38809.html)
- [Synonymisches Handwörterbuch der deutschen Sprache
  von Johann B. Mayer](http://books.google.de/books?id=_NtIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA369&lpg=PA369&dq=froh%20unterschied.%20fr%C3%B6hlich&source=bl&ots=Pc3NuUetgg&sig=X0dqudzKKZcXwnN4JMlvSGgdjAU&hl=de&sa=X&ei=CCPYUN_PK5L24QSz1IGgDw&ved=0CI0BEOgBMAg#v=onepage&q=froh%20unterschied.%20fr%C3%B6hlich&f=false)

Answer (score 6):

Ich denke, *fröhlich* ist eher ein temporärer Zustand, der nach außen sichtbar ist. Man kann *fröhlich* an Sprache, Gesichtsausdruck und Körpersprache erkennen. Wenn jemand lacht oder vor Freude singt und tanz, dann ist er fröhlich.

> Du bist aber fröhlich heute.
>   Wir hatten eine fröhliche Gesellschaft.
>   Das ist ein fröhliches Lied.

Im Unterschied dazu ist *froh* eher ein innerer Zustand von Glück, den man nicht nach außen sehen kann und der eher dauerhaft anhält. *Froh* kann auch *erleichert* bedeuten.

> Ich bin froh, dass meine Kinder gesund sind.
>   Wir waren alle froh, dass die Weihnachtsgeschenke pünktlich gekommen waren.

Answer (score 6):

Ich halte *froh* und *fröhlich* nicht für Synonyme. Die beiden Wörter haben zwar eine sehr ähnliche Bedeutung, aber eben nicht dieselbe. Um ehrlich zu sein, habe ich auch nie verstanden, warum man sich »frohe Weihnachten« und »frohe Ostern« wünscht wenn man sich mit nur einer Silbe mehr viel sinnvoller »fröhliche Weihnachten« und »fröhliche Ostern« wünschen könnte.

### froh

Wenn man sich über das Eintreffen eines Ereignisses freut, das einen als negativ empfundenen Zustand beendet, ist man *froh*. Soldaten sind froh wenn der Krieg zu Ende ist, Eltern sind froh wenn der Sohnemann endlich in eine eigene Wohnung zieht, und der (Ex-)Arbeitslose ist froh, wenn er eine Beschäftigung gefunden hat.

*Froh* hat also die Bedeutung von *glücklich* oder *erleichtert*.

### fröhlich

Wenn Kinder aus reiner Lebensfreude herumtanzen und singen sind sie fröhlich. Die Gäste einer Tanzveranstaltung sind fröhlich und Arbeitskollegen, die bei einer Weihnachtsfeier gemeinsam laut und falsch singen sind auch fröhlich. Niemand würde sagen, dass diese Leute froh wären.

*Fröhlich* bedeutet also *ausgelassen*.

Comment: Ich würde sagen, dass der Wünschende bei den beiden Versionen "frohe" bzw. "fröhliche" Weihnachten/Ostern entweder (unbewusst) den Konventionen folgt, mit denen er aufgewachsen ist, oder bewusst eben entweder ein eher spirituell *frohes* Fest mit besinnlich/religiösem Fokus wünscht oder ein *fröhliches*. Ersteres vielleicht eher typisch für den deutschen Sprachraum, zweiteres eher z.B. für den anglophonen.