# Unterschied zwischen "froh", "zufrieden" und "glücklich"

Tags: difference, usage, adjective, meaning-in-context

Obwohl es sich bei diesen Wörtern nicht um Synonyme handelt, kann man sie alle im Wörterbuch als *happy* übersetzt finden, wenngleich auch unter anderen Bedeutungen (satisfied, lucky, content …).

Nach meiner Erfahrung ist der Unterschied wie folgt, bin mir aber nicht ganz sicher und bitte daher darum zu bestätigen, ob das stimmt.

> **zufrieden**: mit etwas, das ich habe oder mit jemandem, der etwas getan hat. Ich brauche nicht mehr.
>
> > *Ich bin zufrieden mit deinem Benehmen, mein Sohn.*
>
> **froh**: voller Freude, nicht traurig. Ich erlebe einen guten Moment.
>
> > *Die Sonne scheint, heute ist Samstag, ich bin froh.*
>
> **glücklich**: etwas könnte schlecht gehen, hat aber nicht.
>
> > *A: Wie geht es dir?*
> > *B: Ich bin glücklich. Meine Kinder haben Arbeit.*

Comment: Regarding "froh", also have a look at [Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen “froh” und “fröhlich”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5821/1224)

Comment: Meine Frage wäre nachhakend: "Du bist froh, aber froh über was?"

Answer (score 5):

Den Unterschied zwischen "zufrieden" (am ehesten: "content, satisfied") und "froh" (am ehesten: "glad") hast Du gut wiedergegeben.

Die Beschreibung von "glücklich" stimmt aber nicht ganz. Es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen "glücklich sein" und "Glück haben". Deine Interpretation entspricht mehr der Form "Glück haben". Ich versuche einmal, das hier an zwei Beispielen zu verdeutlichen.

> Ich habe Glück gehabt – mein Sohn hat Arbeit

Hier ist zumeist impliziert: Etwas hätte schiefgehen können, ist aber gut gegangen.

Beispiel: Eine Fabrik wird geschlossen, 1000 Menschen verlieren ihre Arbeit. Mein Sohn ist nicht darunter – ich habe Glück gehabt.

> Ich bin glücklich – mein Sohn hat Arbeit

Hier ist zumeist *nicht* impliziert, dass etwas hätte schiefgehen können. Stattdessen drückt man aus, dass man mit einem bestimmten Zustand sehr, sehr zufrieden ist – hier ist es also eine Art Steigerung von "zufrieden" (vgl. "happy" vs "satisfied").

Beispiel: Mein Sohn hat gerade sein Studium beendet. Nun hat er seine erste Arbeitsstelle begonnen. Ich bin glücklich, dass er diesen wichtigen Schritt in seinem Leben gemacht hat.

Answer (score 2):

Bei "zufrieden" ist ein Erwartungswert ausreichend erfüllt.

"Froh" bedeutete früher "positiv gestimmt" (siehe: 'Lasst uns froh und munter sein', 'frohgemut' oder 'Frohsinn'), ist in dieser Bedeutung aber veraltet; es bedeutet heute viel eher bewusste Freude über erhaschtes Glück.

"Glücklich" ist ein allgemeiner Zustand starker positiver Gefühle.

"Glücklich" schließt demzufolge "zufrieden" oft mit ein, wobei aber auch ein sehr hoch angesetzter Erwartungswert selbst dann noch nicht erreicht sein braucht, obwohl man bereits "glücklich" ist; in dem Falle wäre man selbst im Glücklichsein noch nicht zufrieden. "Frohsein" ist aber normalerweise noch kein Glücklichsein bzw. Zufriedenheit, denn man hat hier eher nur dem Negativen ausweichen können.